# .htaccess non-www redirect creating error 404?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Error: The requested URL /public_html/ was not found on this server.

Instead of going to http://www.mywebsite.com/, my 301 redirect in the .htaccess file is sending the browser to http://www.mywebsite.com/public_html/ and throwing that error.

This may have something to do with the fact that I am hosting an add-on domain in a subdirectory? The issue only comes up when using InMotion.com hosting, the same code works fine on a page I am hosting on Bluehost.

.htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have seen this before and I'm having trouble remembering exactly what fixed it, but see if changing the rule to `RewriteRule ^/?public_html/(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]` sorts it out (it might just break it further). IIRC the problem was that something internal to Apache has altered the request URI *before* it gets to mod_rewrite, rather than afterwards, I'm just digging around to try and find the actual reference for this.

Comment: That eliminated the 404 error, but the page just loads as mysite.com and not www.mysite.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has always worked for me. (Note the backslash before ".com")

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```